# Thunderbird issue with proxy authentication

Tags: thunderbird, proxy, authentication

I was setting up Thunderbird at home with wired Internet connection, and everything was fine.

However when I tried getting new mails using college wireless which requires proxy with authentication, after typed my username and password, Thunderbird status bar showed some progress, then I received this error:

> Could not connect to mail server abcd@abcd.com, the connection was refused.

Ironically, I still be able to open tab for browsing some addons, but could not able to download them. 
I assumed since Firefox works so well under proxy (to both Thunderbird and FF, I used the setting in Edit -> Pref -> Advance -> Network Tab -> Connection), Thunderbird would conduct the same and work fine.

I'm currently using Ubuntu Oneiric.

Answer (score 3):

For what it is worth, my situation was similar. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and the latest version of Thunderbird. I am updated with Ubuntu: this means apt-get is working through our proxy server. Basic web browsing with Mozilla Firefox is working through our proxy. I posted my answer in Thunderbird's forum to share what I did, but basically, after authenticating on our proxy server with the web browser, I connected to Thunderbird with NO PROXY SETTINGS. Very weird. But it worked. Here is my complete post:

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=2449619

Hope this helps,

-Mike-